# Syntax For Calling Methods In Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I come from a PHP background and I'm used to calling a class' internal methods with $this->methodName(), but I can't seem to find the syntax for doing the same in Rails. I want to do something like the following in a controller:

```
class Foo

  def bar
   #call self.baz
  end

  def baz
    #some code
  end

end
```

What is the proper syntax for the method call? Also, if there is a good place for just learning basic syntax for Ruby/Rails, please share. I'm finding it frustrating just trying to find simple syntax features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simply `baz` or `self.baz`. `self` is equivalent to `$this` in PHP.

Comment: When would I use baz vs. self.baz? Is there a distinction?

Comment: No. But if you override `baz` for example by define local variable called `baz` then you can always call class method `baz` using `self.baz`. Also some programmers prefer that way to explicit show that it is class method.

Comment: @Hauleth: `self.baz` does not refer to a class method in this case. `self` in an instance method refers to the instance; `self` in a class method refers to the class singleton. For example, `def self.method_name` in a class body creates a class method because `self` refers to the singleton -- in this case it would be equivalent to `def Foo.method_name`.

Comment: Also, I've read somewhere that Ruby does a bit of caching with local variables, so `baz` should be a bit faster than `self.baz`. I didn't check it, though, so if anyone has more complete information on the topic, please correct/confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's syntax is pretty simple - just call `.method_name` on the object:

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.bar # calls bar on foo
```

Within a method defintion `self` (which Rubyists call the "receiver") is implicit, so just use the method name:

```
def bar
  baz # calls Foo#baz
end
```

You can also use `self` explicitly to do the same thing:

```
def bar
  self.baz # also calls Foo#baz
end
```

A good introduction to Ruby syntax can be found [here](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/).